# Cannot import ocrmypdf & tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-3.11, ocrmypdf

I have a strange issue. Strange, because I did the same thing on my home PC and had no problem - but when I tried it on my work PC it somehow did not work and I really don't get the issue.

So, I am trying to use ocrmypdf in Python and have installed it and all the prerequisits via pip.

Yet, whenever I try to import it, either program I might use for it will tell me that there is no module named "ocrmypdf" or for the matter a module named "tesseract".

I tried deinstalling and reinstalling python and then tesseract/ocrmypdf, but it did exactly nothing.

I have to be overlooking something, but I cannot think of anything else to do.

Comment: I would say that probably your problem is that you have more than one python installation, and the one you are installing the libraries to, is not the one you are running it from; consequently they are missing.
on a mac ```which python``` will show you all the python installs. 
if you have more than one, the you will have to profix python with the version; for example: ```python3.12```
check the libraries you have installed in that specific install; for example: ```python3.12 -m pip list```